# Python Class and Objects

Tags: python, oop

I have made the following user class.

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, ID, gender, age_group, city):
        self.ID = ID
        self.gender = gender
        self.age_group = age_group
        self.city = city
```

I later make two objects of class User and append them in a list.

```
uList = []

u1=User('Alice','f','20-35','abs')
u2=User('Bob','m','35-50','xyz')

uList.append(u1)
uList.append(u2)
```

I save this user list using the pickle library.

I can obviously access each object from this list as : uList[0], uList[1]

The ID in data is a unique identifier for each user. My question is given a ID can I retrieve the entire object so that I can get the corresponding attributes?

I can always use a Dictionary as follows:

```
uList = {}
uList['Alice']=u1
uList['BoB']=u2
```

Is this the only way? Is there a better way?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: A dict is fine. FWIW, you could use namedtuples instead of a custom class to store your data. If you definitely want to use a class, consider using [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to reduce RAM requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should actually look into the [Shelve](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shelve.html) library. It's essentially a dictionary that uses a pickle to become persistent.